# Is it true that Jodorowsky killed all the lambs himself for the crucifixion procession in The Holy Mountain?

Tags: production, the-holy-mountain

I heard this story through oral tradition (an artist friend and Jodorowsky expert related the tale to me.)  Essentially, the story goes, no one wanted to slaughter all of the lambs necessary for the procession scene in [The Holy Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holy_Mountain_(1973_film)) and so [Jodorowsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alejandro_Jodorowsky) took it upon himself in service of his vision (aka "getting the shot") breaking the necks of the multitude of lambs required.

Has anyone else heard this story? There is a [discussion of the scene here](http://jodorowsky.tribe.net/thread/cf368876-7843-4153-94c6-11b141460bb2) and this is a [New York Times response to the film from 1974](http://www.nytimes.com/1974/01/13/archives/they-kill-animals-and-they-call-it-art-more-and-more-directors-are.html?_r=0), but I can't find anything on Snopes debunking the claim.

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071615/trivia?item=tr0762131) trivia on IMDB where it's written that

> The crucified animal carcasses were borrowed from a local restaurant,
>   which were then served to customers upon being returned.

I don't know the truth and I can't find the source of this but I think it could be interesting.